# Unconventional vector multiplication with numpy

Tags: python, algorithm, math, numpy, scipy

I'm interested in multiplying numbers in an unconventional way.  Suppose you are multiplying like this:

```
out = a * b * c * d
```

`out` will be positive if all inputs are positive, all inputs are negative, or two inputs are positive and two are negative (let's ignore 0).

Instead of this conventional math, I would like the sign of the output to be positive only if all inputs are positive or all inputs are negative.  Otherwise, the output is negative.

It is straightforward to implement this for scalars, but I would like to do this for element-by-element vector multiplication with numpy.  Is there an easy way to implement this in numpy?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One approach is to separately compute the absolute value and the sign as follows:

```
import numpy as np

A = np.array([2,2,2,-2])
B = np.array([2,3,-2,-3])
C = np.array([2,-2,-4,-2])
D = np.array([2,5,2,-2])

M = abs(A*B*C*D)
S = np.sign(A) + np.sign(B) + np.sign(C) + np.sign(D)
M = np.where( (S==4) + (S==-4) ,M,-M)

print M
```

prints:

```
[ 16 -60 -32  24]
```

S will equal 4 if all elements are positive, -4 if all negative.  So in these cases we select the positive version of the result, otherwise the negative.